# How to get the current view page in a PHP MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Im trying to get the current page using a custom php MVC

here is the link example:

**http://localhost/microvines/videomanager**

I want to get the current page from the link above so that I can use it to check for the current active page in a ul list ..

```
<li class="active">
```

How to retrieve **videomanager** From the link above?

**Update:**

for the controller Im using this class

**videomanager.php**

```
class Videomanager extends Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        Auth::handleLogin();    

    }   
    public function index(){        
        $this->view->Videos = $this->model->fetchVideos();          
        $this->view->render('videomanager/index');      
    }   
}
```

**Model** : videomanager_model.php

```
class Videomanager_Model extends Model {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function fetchVideos(){      
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM bv_videos AS v 
                                    LEFT JOIN bv_categories AS c 
                                    ON v.cat_id=c.cat_id 
                                    ORDER BY v.video_id DESC");     
        $stmt->execute();   

        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $stmt->fetchAll();       
    }
}
```

**View**

```
    <ul>        
            <li class="active"> 
              <a href="<?php echo URL ?>videomanager">
                <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-star"></span>
                <span class="sidebar-title">Dashboard</span>
              </a> 
            </li>
    ......
```

Comment: We can't know how your custom mvc framework works.

Comment: I'd guess that would be done in your router logic / the particular controller relating to the requested page. But since we have no knowledge how your custom framework works, we can't possibly do much. Adding some code might help.

Comment: I updated my question and added some codes to show I my custom mvc working

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked fine.

```
$current_page = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$current_page = $current_page[2];
```